# Excel max number between 2 non-blank cells A, in column B (given no blanks in B)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to calculate the maximum number between 2 consecutive non-blank cells in A, but using the values in B. ie. use a formula in column C that will give me the results I manually plotted in D. Bearing in mind the amount of non-blank cells between figures in A is completely random. 
calulations:

> D1 = max(B1:B2) {values in range determing by x}
>   D3 = max(B3) {values in the range determined by y}
>   D4 = max(B4:B6) {values in the range determined by z}

```
  A B C D
1 x 0 1
2   1   
3 y 1 1
4 z 2 3
5   0
6   3
```

I've tried using these, but no luck with either:

```
INDEX(A2:A25;MATCH(FALSE;ISBLANK(A2:A25);0))
```

and

```
MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK (B2:B25)), ROW(B2:B25),0))
```

Comment: I don't understand how the values in D relate to those shown in B and A. Could you add a description showing how you derived D? You might need to add row numbers, in order that you can say something like "D1 is the maximum number between B1 (matches x) and B2 (row above y)" -- write in plain English what you actually did to get column D.

Comment: Your question is unclear - please elaborate more -

Comment: Can you accept VBa?

Comment: Why is the value in D4 =MAX(B4:B6)? Is that to assume that A7 is non-blank (we can't see that cell in your table)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

`=IF(A1<>"",MAX(OFFSET(B1,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH("*",OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(B:B)-ROW()+1),0),COUNTA(B:B)-ROW()+1))),"")`

[image]

To get the height of your data I used `COUNTA()` on column B, it will work correctly only if you don't have blank cells in column B.

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. However, my example was a simplified version. In reality, it's columns AHE I'm talking about, hence A=A; B=H; C=E. To make things a little more complicated, I would only use the values in H given the value in I for a certain row is blank. Does this make sense? So the table I'm using goes from A1:I1069

The formula you provided would hence be plotted into E2 as:
         =IF(A2<>"";MAX(OFFSET(H2;0;0;IFERROR(MATCH("*";OFFSET(A3;0;0;COUNTA(H:H)-ROW()+1);0);COUNTA(B:B)-ROW()+1)));"")

But this should only be used if there is no value in I2.

@andrew